# what is wrong with my code why don't I see the white rectangle when i run the code. draw.rect() command

Tags: python, pygame, drawing

when I try to run the code the white square that is supposed to be there does not pop up.
I've tried to replace the variables with the numbers corresponding to them but it does not work either.
this is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
# vars for window Height,width, and resolution'
WIN_WIDTH = 1100
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
WIN_RES = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
# Width & height for grid behind background + color of the grid
WIDTH = 100
HEIGHT = 100 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
# Create window
GAME_WINDOW = display.set_mode(WIN_RES)
# To Do Add window caption/title here
display.set_caption("Attack of the vampire pizzas")
# background & vampire pizza image
pizza_img = image.load('vampire.png')
pizza_surf = Surface.convert_alpha(pizza_img)
VAMPIRE_PIZZA = transform.scale(pizza_surf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
background_img = image.load('restaurant.jpg')
background_surf = Surface.convert_alpha(background_img)
BACKGROUND = transform.scale(background_surf, WIN_RES)
GAME_WINDOW.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))

GAME_WINDOW.blit(VAMPIRE_PIZZA, (900, 400))
# actual grid
tile_color = WHITE

draw.rect(BACKGROUND, tile_color, (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 1)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Start main game loop
game_running = True
# game loop
while game_running:
# check for events
for event in pygame.event.get():

    # Exit loop on quit
    if event.type == QUIT:
        game_running = False
display.update()
# End of main game loop
# Clean up game
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: your code has syntax errors

Comment: where? i dont see any

Comment: What about the indentation?

Comment: i dont need it for the things that are not in loops

Comment: The indentation in your code snippet is wrong. Don't you see it? How can we help you since you post code with incorrect indentation?

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The event loop and `display.update()` must be run in the game loop. Additionally you need to draw the rectangle in the game window in the application loop:

```py
# Start main game loop
game_running = True
# game loop
while game_running:

    # INDENTATION
#-->|
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Exit loop on quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            game_running = False

    GAME_WINDOW.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
    GAME_WINDOW.blit(VAMPIRE_PIZZA, (900, 400))
    draw.rect(GAME_WINDOW, tile_color, (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 1)

    # INDENTATION
#-->|
    display.update()

# End of main game loop
# Clean up game
pygame.quit()
```

Note, you have to redraw the scene in every frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)